# Detect key presses on Start Capturing Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, screen-capture

#### Problem Description

I'm using Native Screen Recording functionality provided by Android. When I start recording System popups Dialog and ask user to confirm that screen can be recorder. If user press outside dialog dismissed (same behaviour when he/she press cancel) when press Start Now Recording Start.

#### Question

1. **How I can detect what user pressed**

   - Cancel
   - Start Now
   - Dismissed on press outside
2. **How can I disable dismiss on press outside of dialog**
3. **Is there a way to avoid showing dialog?**

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code , how you are creating the dialog..?

Comment: @sandeep I'm not creating this Dialog, this Dialog is shown by System ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can detect what user pressed

You can determine if the user pressed "Start Now" as part of your normal media projection flow. For example, when you pass the `onActivityResult()` data to `getMediaProjection()`, `getMediaProjection()` will only give you a `MediaProjection` object if the user pressed "Start Now".

You cannot distinguish between "Cancel", "click outside the dialog", pressing the BACK button, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> on a device with a physical keyboard, or any other means of dismissing this dialog.

> How can I disable dismiss on press outside of dialog

The decision on how to handle this is up to the system, not you.

> Is there a way to avoid showing dialog?

No.